# Java JNI call dll that connect database via OLEDB Jet 4.0 (dBase IV) with Borland Database Engine (BDE) crash in JRE 7 Environment

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, oledb, dbase

My java project have called dll (C# Project) that connect dBase (IV) database via OleDB jet 4.0 with Borland Database Engine (BDE).

I didn't found any error when I run my java project with JRE 6.0 but I found crash when I run it with JRE 7.0.

I try to debug with Windows Debuging (WinDbg) for finding what is difference between JRE 6.0 and JRE 7.0 environment. I found error in dll process when it try to connect database.

```
    internal bool LoadTable(String _provider, String _prop, String _datasource,
                            String _table, ref DataTable _dt, ref String _error)
    {
        ....
        db = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        db.Open();//Error Here.
        ....
    }
```

Trace in Windows Debuging tell me it has crash when it call dependency dll (IDAPI32.DLL) to connect database.

**JRE 7.0**

```
[Trace] Connection string: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\SOME_PATH\DATA\;Extended Properties=dBase IV;
[Trace] Create database connection.
[Trace] Opening database.
ModLoad: 00000000`6a830000 00000000`6a8d3000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Transactions\ea4b09c3c6f55fc808fae12477465c1b\System.Transactions.ni.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6bd20000 00000000`6bd67000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`72b00000 00000000`72b5f000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`676a0000 00000000`67774000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71630000 00000000`7164f000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSDART.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`72a30000 00000000`72a47000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6ca20000 00000000`6ca34000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\OLEDB32R.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`75390000 00000000`7539e000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64pcRtRemote.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`631f0000 00000000`63326000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comsvcs.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6bd00000 00000000`6bd14000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ATL.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`72960000 00000000`7299d000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6afa0000 00000000`6affa000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msjetoledb40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71350000 00000000`714d5000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msjet40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71290000 00000000`71328000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswstr10.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71260000 00000000`71271000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msjter40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71250000 00000000`71256000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSJINT40.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`635b0000 00000000`63626000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxbde40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`4bde0000 00000000`4be7a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\IDAPI32.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`753b0000 00000000`753c2000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MPR.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`4c9e0000 00000000`4ca06000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\IDR20007.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`4e8e0000 00000000`4e904000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\BANTAM.DLL
(1380.e30): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\IDAPI32.DLL
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\IDAPI32.DLL - 
IDAPI32!DbiRenameTable+0x3075:
4be3a2d1 85c0            test    eax,eax
```

I didn't found this crash when call my project with JRE 6.0 Environment.

**JRE 6.0**

```
[Trace] Connection string: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\SOME_PATH\DATA\;Extended Properties=dBase IV;
[Trace] Create database connection.
[Trace] Opening database.
ModLoad: 00000000`6bcf0000 00000000`6bd93000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Transactions\ea4b09c3c6f55fc808fae12477465c1b\System.Transactions.ni.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6afb0000 00000000`6aff7000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`72b00000 00000000`72b5f000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6a800000 00000000`6a8d4000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71900000 00000000`7191f000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSDART.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`72a30000 00000000`72a47000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71740000 00000000`71754000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\OLEDB32R.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`75390000 00000000`7539e000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`67850000 00000000`67986000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comsvcs.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71630000 00000000`71644000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ATL.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`72960000 00000000`7299d000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6ad40000 00000000`6ad9a000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msjetoledb40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71350000 00000000`714d5000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msjet40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71290000 00000000`71328000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswstr10.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71260000 00000000`71271000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msjter40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`71250000 00000000`71256000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSJINT40.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`677d0000 00000000`67846000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxbde40.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`4bde0000 00000000`4be7a000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\IDAPI32.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`753b0000 00000000`753c2000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MPR.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`4c9e0000 00000000`4ca06000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\IDR20007.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`4e8e0000 00000000`4e904000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\BANTAM.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`67710000 00000000`677d0000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\ed906f21883851cfbb9bd06b0d2a4daa\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6cb20000 00000000`6cb3f000   System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`0f2e0000 00000000`0f2ff000   System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6c640000 00000000`6c67e000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\ed906f21883851cfbb9bd06b0d2a4daa\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`6cb20000 00000000`6cb3f000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
[Trace] Query with sql: SELECT * FROM XXXX.DBF
[Trace] Add data to data table
ModLoad: 00000000`4dde0000 00000000`4de56000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Gemeinsame Dateien\BDE\IDDBAS32.DLL
ModLoad: 00000000`6af80000 00000000`6afa7000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Numerics\de2a832558f95db343e443c365bd3575\System.Numerics.ni.dll
[Trace] bla bla bla....
[Trace] Close database.
```

**Additional Environment Info (JRE 6 and 7)**
- .Net Framework Version 4.0.30319.34209 
- OS Architecture 32bits (x86) when run program.
- OS Windows 7 64Bits

What is difference environment between JRE 6 and 7 than have effect to crash on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but the difference could be the dll search path.

One thing to try is to use procmon to track file accesses up to the point of failure. See which paths it was attempting to load that idapi32 dll from.

You can also sometimes get better information using the old depends.exe utility to launch the jre...

For sure, even if you get this one issue figured out, you will want to catch whatever exception is getting thrown and review as a java exception.

Finally, if you are looking for a type 4 odbc/ado driver, izmado has one that is very reasonably priced.  We've used it in probably a hundred deployments with no issues. Sometimes it's best not to recreate the wheel!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kevin for guiding. I use depends.exe for check dll's dependency. I found some clue in dll environment that may be the main cause of this problem.

I found JRE 6.0 that can call JNI complete without crash because JRE 6.0 have similar environment BDE (VC++ 6.0 and VC++ 7.1) but JRE 7.0 didn't similar environment BDE.

**Borland Database Engine (BDE)** is the old legacy system. It was created from vc++ version 6.0.

The **java.dll** from JRE 6.0 was created from vc++ version 7.1 (MS VC++ 2003).

The **java.dll** from JRE 7.0 was created from vc++ version 10.0 (MS VC++ 2010).

I prove this hypothesis with creating exe to call module in JNI. We found the exe that was created by MS VC++ 2010 found the same problem but the exe that was created by MS VC++ 2003 didn't found problem.

I solve this problem with changing the database provider from BDE to database provider from Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010. (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)